# get data and insert in csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python trying to make a code that will give me infromation in csv file of c drive freespace and existance of software path.

below is the code I am trying..

```
import time
import csv
import os
import socket
import ctypes
import platform
import sys

timestr = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")

filepath = r"D:\_library\_abcd\test"
filename = timestr + ".csv"

machinename = socket.gethostname()
print machinename

def Get_free_space_mb(direname):
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        free_bytes = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExW(ctypes.c_wchar_p(direname),None, None, ctypes.pointer(free_bytes))
        print(free_bytes.value / 1024 / 1024 )
        return free_bytes.value / 1024 / 1024
    else:
        st = os.statvfs(dirname)
        return st.f_bavail * st.f_frsize / 1024 / 1024

Cdrivespace = Get_free_space_mb("C:\\")

def software1():
    if os.path.isdir("C:\Program Files\software1"):
        return "software1 Exist"
    else:
        return "software1 not Exist"
software_1 = software1()

def software2():
    if os.path.isdir("C:\Program Files\software2"):
        return "software2 Exist"
    else:
        return "Nuke9 not Exist"
software_2 = software2()

def software3():
    if os.path.isdir("C:\Program Files\software3"):
        return "software3 Exist"
    else:
        return "software3 not Exist"
software_3 = software3()

with open(os.path.join(filepath,filename), 'ab+') as file_:
writer = csv.writer(file_,delimiter=",")
data = [machinename,Cdrivespace,software1,software2,software3]
writer.writerows([data])
```

The output I am getting in csv is :
(SUPT5) (10150) (function software1 at 0x02AF47B0)  (function software2 at 0x02AF4A70)  (function software3 at 0x02AF4AB0)

what is expected output is :
(SUPT5) (10150**MB**)   (software1 exist)  (software2 exist) (software3 not exist)

also I want to csv file to write mb after  writing value of Cdrivespace.
anything changes which I can make to code more easy ?

Comment: suggestion - instead of writing 3 separate functions sw1, sw2, sw3, combine into one and pass arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `data` line:

```
data = [machinename, str(Cdrivespace) + 'MB', software_1, software_2, software_3]
```

You were referencing the `software1` etc. functions, not the returned values (`software_1` etc).